# Volume mixer don't show my program

Tags: vb.net

I used awesomium as web browser for my program but there is no control in Volume control.
How can i add this option in volume control because some site have sounds.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is a question and answer site for *programming related questions*. You have shown no code, no error messages, no screenshots - how can we possibly help?

Comment: I need help to create code to control my application volume in `Volume Control` in windows.Some article or help to start this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find answer for awesonium web browser, so i switch my browser to geckofx browser that you can download [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx)